# Linked-list assignment operator

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to figure out if i have the general idea behind the assignment operator for Doubly Linked Lists using a current node (no front or back). This is my pseudo code. I need to get this concept down. If anyone can help, that would be sweet.

```
Loop to start
    temp = temp->back
loop to count
    if 0
        receiver->back = null
        receiver->entry = temp->entry
        receiver->next = temp->next
    if > 0
        receiver->back = temp->back
        receiver->entry = temp->entry
        receiver->next = temp->next
    if == count-1
        receiver->back = temp->back
        receiver->entry = temp->entry
        receiver->next = null
```

This is my Node structure:

```
struct Node {
    // data members
    Node_entry entry;
    Node<Node_entry> *next;
    Node<Node_entry> *back;
    // constructors
    Node();
    Node(Node_entry, Node<Node_entry> *link_back = nullptr, 
        Node<Node_entry> *link_next = nullptr);

}
```

I'm not looking for a code answer, but an algorithm (actually code that is well commented and written is good as example). I just need to understand how the copying works.

Comment: Are you asking how to copy a doubly linked list?

Comment: We need more information about your particular list implementation.  In C++ (which you tagged with originally), it's common to have a "container" class that represents the entire list, which simplifies this considerably.  (It seems you're dealing with plain nodes and probably pointers to a single node to represent a full list.)

Comment: I want to know how to copy it, but i'm not looking for specific code as an answer, more like the algorithm. I just want to get the concept, so i can understand how it works.

Comment: Algorithms are code; that's what I answered below.  Incidentally, my guess as to your node class isn't far off from what you're actually using. :)

Comment: Ok, lol. I have a lot to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct Node {
  Node *prev, *next;
  int entry;

  explicit Node(int entry) : prev (0), next (0), entry (entry) {}
};

Node* copy_list(Node *node) {
  assert(node);  // require a non-null pointer

  // copy "current" node
  Node *new_list = new Node(node->entry);

  // copy backward from node to beginning
  Node *dest = new_list;
  for (Node *x = node->prev; x; x = x->prev) {
    dest->prev = new Node(x->entry);
    dest->prev->next = dest;
    dest = dest->prev;
  }

  // copy forward from node to end
  dest = new_list;
  for (Node *x = node->next; x; x = x->next) {
    dest->next = new Node(x->entry);
    dest->next->prev = dest;
    dest = dest->next;
  }

  return new_list;
}
```

Comment: Would this code copy the current node twice? If it copies from node backwards and then from node forward doesn't it copy the list with two of the first default node? Furthermore, doesn't it also copy the entries in a different order than received from user? Would it be better to go to start and copy from start?

Comment: @Knownasilya: When copying backwards/forwards, it starts at prev and next, rather than the current node, that's why the current node is copied explicitly first.  It copies in a different order, but stores in the same order; note how dest creates in the same direction as node is walked.

Comment: @Knownasilya: While using a raw Node pointer as your list will work, I highly suggest you follow something closer to std::list and create an "overall" list class.

Comment: It's an assignment, so I can't change any of the header files :(

Comment: @Knownasilya: I think it's silly they don't show you how to encapsulate this, but feel free to ask if you have any more questions.

Comment: What do you mean by "create an 'overall' list class"?

Comment: @Knownasilya: std::list is an example of that; it has an internal node type that it manages, but selectively exposes parts of that node type through iterators.

Comment: For some reason, on the second call of traverse(print) it outputs the last entry and not the whole list. Could this be because of the mutable current_position?  MY Traverse function: http://pastie.org/1270923 I'm passing a cout function to the traverse.

Comment: @Knownasilya: It would be better to ask a new question than do that in comments (e.g. that link will eventually die).  When you traverse the list the first time (in the latter half of the traverse function), you don't update current_position.  For the second call, current_position is 0 but current still points to the last item.

Comment: Ok, next time I'll do the suggested. Thanks for the tip.